Bill draws from a deck of cards repeatedly, with replacement. What is the expected number of draws to get four jacks in a row?
Question above.
I get the method of using recursive expectation which is what you are meant to do but i don't see where this reasoning is going wrong:

Let $A$ be the event of getting 4 jacks in a row. P(A) = $(\frac{1}{13})^4$.
We can model it as a geometric distribution so $X$, the number of draws until we get 4 jacks $\sim Geo(\frac{1}{13})^4$
So $E(X) = 1/ (\frac{1}{13})^4 = 28561$

The answer is $30940$

You are answering a different question.  Your calculation answers the question "suppose you are drawing in groups of $4$, with replacement.  How many groups of four do you expect you'll need to draw before you get a group with four Jacks?"  That isn't what you were asked.  The draw sequence $5KJJJJ$ is a win for the given question, but not for yours.

Usual method is to use states.  Keep track of the running number of Jacks in your sequence.  Work out the expected number of tries to finish given that you start in any given state.

It is not a coincidence that $30940=13^1+13^2+13^3+13^4$.  Your attempt only has $28561=13^4$.

If we let a,b,c,d represent start/no useful draws, one Jack, two consecutive Jacks, three consecutive Jacks respectively, we get the step by step equations
$$a = 1+\frac1{13}b + \frac{12}{13}a \tag1$$
$$b = 1+\frac1{13}c + \frac{12}{13}a \tag2$$
$$c = 1+\frac1{13}d + \frac{12}{13}a \tag3$$
$$d = 1+\frac{12}{13}a \tag4$$
[From d, with one draw we are either done or revert to start]
Solving the system of linear equations, we get $a = 30940$

There is a slicker way of arriving at a solution for such problems using Conway's algorithm, (not to be confused with Conway's Doomsday algorithm) which successively assigns Y or N to the string if entries are identical starting from left and ending at right, or not, of succeeding (moving forward) or failing

length $1$: Y
length $2$: Y
length $3$: Y
length $4$: Y

The # of draws needed would thus be  $\sum 13^L (L=\;length)$ for lengths having a $Y$
$=13 + 13^2 + 13^3 + 13^4 = 30940$
